# Navigation bar Type selector doesn't automatically jump to coded method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ide

In VS 15 (2017), the Type dropdown in the navigation bar no longer automatically jumps to a coded method, if there is one. Previously, when I selected a button from the Type dropdown, the code window automatically scrolled the Click handler into view (if I had coded the event). Now I have to select the type and then choose Click from the Method dropdown, even if that is the only event coded.

Is there an option I can change to make it work as before?

See also:
[Visual Studio 2015 navigation bar event dropdown not auto-selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932271/visual-studio-2015-navigation-bar-event-dropdown-not-auto-selecting)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but... if you know the name of the control you can cntrl + f for it. Also, you can rightClick > "find all references" on items in code to jump to anywhere else it's used. Between those two things, I've never needed to use those dropdown things.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know about the other ways to get to a method. I'm just lamenting a useful feature that's apparently been lost in VS 15.